# Netflow Collector for Windows Free

Tags: windows, networking, cisco, netflow

Is there a free [netflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflow) collector that I can throw on a windows box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) can act as a NetFlow collector and is available for Win32. You will have to recompile it by yourself though, or find pre-made builds (shouldn't be too hard, it's GPLv3 open source) since the provided build is limited to capturing 1000 packets per session.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is offered by SolarWinds:

http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/netflow_analyzer.aspx

- has an add-on product to help you configure your Cisco router interfaces correctly
- only supports NetFlow v5
- limited to 60 minutes of data

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Scrutinizer free version:

http://www.plixer.com/products/free-netflow.php

Free Version:

```
* Supports an unlimited amount of flow sending devices!!!
* Network Mapping: Click Here for more details
* Top Conversations
* Top Hosts
* Top Protocols
* Application Groups: Viewing Application Groups and Define Application Groups
* Quality of Service link to display the top ToS and DiffServ priority tags.
* Displays the Autonomous Systems.
* Drag and Drill Technology to drill in on time frames
* Status Tab
* Displays the volume of traffic for the selected host or port on the selected interface(s).
* Displays the volume of unique conversations to (green) and from (blue) for the selected host or port on the selected interface(s).
* Vitals Tab
* SNMPv3 Support
* Integration with 3rd party products
* All flow data dropped at midnight (NOTE: One year trends of total in / out traffic are provided)
* Denika free plugin to discover & display the SNMP statistics for a device. Includes Cisco's IP SLA and NBAR technologies.
* Search for a specific host or application.
* Google Maps
* Free Initial Setup via Telephone Support
* Support from the Email Forum
```

Comment: I tried scrutinizer a while ago and from memery I had trouble slicing up the traffic from each interface by port. (which is what I wanted to do)

Answer (score 0):

Scrutinizer drops all netflow data at midnight in its free version.

ManageEngine's Netflow Analyzer free version is limited to monitoring two interfaces, but it doesn't drop data.  http://www.manageengine.com/products/netflow/index.html